# walletconnect and metmask on mobile pre transaction confirmation eventError

Tags: metamask, walletconnect

I am using a local dev test node and connecting my daap via walletConnect. i am having issues with all transactions where they throw the following error :

```
Error: Internal JSON-RPC error.
    at events.ts:67
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at EventManager.trigger (events.ts:65)
    at WalletConnect._handleIncomingMessages (index.ts:982)
```

before the transaction is confirmed, and showing so on the metamask mobile wallet.
what can be the reason for this ? my local node ? it does work correctly with chrome plugin metamask.

Comment: Well, it might have sth to do with your array.` Array.forEach` this might be the issue.It would be better to provide the part of the code that's throwing the error. That way you can get a better answer.

Comment: i don't think it has anything to do with any code, it's probably metamask